# Access credential for EMR Jupyter Notebook

Tags: amazon-emr, jupyterhub

I just set up an EMR cluster with built-in Spark, JupyterHub and so on. I am able to access the Jupyter Notebook at [http://**master_hostname**:9443/hub/login](http://__master_hostname__:9443/hub/login) but I have no idea what credential I can use to log in or where I can set this up in the EMR.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As documented here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub-user-access.html

the default admin is named "jovyan" and the password is "jupyter" :)